# problem with function on the lside of an assignment

Tags: c++, function, templates

I have this tuple defined inside a test case,

```
std::tuple<int, string, string, double> t1 = { 1321, "xxxx", "xxxx", 1.68 }
```

and i have to write a function unpack where i should be able to do this:

```
int key; string first_name; string last_name; double height;
unpack(key, first_name, last_name, height) = t1;
```

I can't change the definitions above because they are in a test case and i can't modify that.

I know that the function should be declared something like this:

```
&unpack()
```

I should use templates but i don't know how. Thanks for the answers.

Comment: This exists already: [`std::tie`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie)

Comment: It doesn't sound like much, but tack on a quick example and I think you have an answer, @tkausl

Comment: do you need to write the function `unpack` or do you need a function that you can use the way you describe?

Comment: i can't use std::tie because it does not appear in the test case that my function should pass. So i have to write the function unpack but i don't have any idea how to do that.

Comment: If you change your question after having received answers, I suggest you make it clear what the changes are.

Comment: sorry, i'll keep that in mind for duture posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have to write the function because the definition of the tuple and the assignment are in a test case and i can't modify that.

```
template <class... Args>
constexpr decltype(auto) unpack(Args&&... args) noexcept
{
    return std::tie(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use structured bindings if you have access to `C++17`:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <string>

std::tuple<int, string, string, double> tpl = { 1321, "xxxx", "xxxx", 1.68 };

const auto& [a,b,c,d] = tpl;
```

If not, then as @tkausl suggested, you can use `std::tie`:

```
...
int a;
string b,c;
double d;

std::tie(a,b,c,d) = tpl;
```

The syntax is clumsy, as you have to define the variables beforehand and therefore cannot make them `const`.

Comment: I have to write the function because the definition of the tuple and the assignment are in a test case and i can't modify that.